# Programmatically download APK from google play store

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am creating an android app which depends on some other android apps. So if these dependent apps are not already there on the users mobile, I would like to download them programmatically from play store. But during this process I don't want the control to go to the Play store app (i.e. no Play store app activity should be visible). Is is possible to achieve this using some service, google API? How do I go about implement this?
I tried the market api and it worked but now while installation I am getting "unknown sources" pop up. Is it possible to get rid of form this ?? What is difference between downloaded apk from play store app and market api ??

Comment: you're not exactly supposed to do that, so i don't think it is possible

Comment: @njzk it's possible, see my answer below

Answer (score 3):

There is an unofficial [market API](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/):
And [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowDownloadApps) is how you can download apps with it.

Comment: Yap it works( at least it worked when I tested it out a few months ago)

Comment: I tried the market api and it worked but now while installation I am getting "unknown sources" pop up. Is it possible to get rid of form this ?? What is difference between downloaded apk from play store app and market api ??

Comment: While this approach downloads the app from the store, it installs it in such a way that it will not be recognized as coming from the store. It will not receive automatic updates. The "unofficial market API" may also stop working at any time and in any way. Depending on internal implementation details of the Play Store in this way is the very soul of What Not To Do When Developing Software.