# How to directly start a download from the Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play

Opening Google Play store on a specific app is pretty straight forward using something like

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=MyApp")));
```

This will open the Play Store, but the user will still have to click the download link. Is it possible to tell the Play Store that the intent is not to *view* the app, but to *download* the app? It's fine if the Play Store still asks the user for confirmation, but I just want to skip the part of showing the user the whole app again - something he already knows he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I found this code from below link

[Programmatically download APK from google play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703982/programmatically-download-apk-from-google-play-store)

and this is a code to just open your app on play sotre

```
          try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=appname")));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appname")));
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Meenal, unfortunately I cannot use an unsupported solution for this product. It's still very informative though.

Comment: @JacobusR which means this is not doable.

Answer (score 0):

jost use "rdid" in Uri:

```
try {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=appname&rdid=appname")));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appname&rdid=appname")));
    }
```